# Android > Chrome Chromecast icon over html5 video position

Tags: html, icons, chromecast

If there is a Chromecast around and:

### If the html5 video controls are enabled, the cast buttons shows up in the control bar.

### If the html5 video controls are disabled, the cast button shows up on the top left.

[image]

I'd like to disable the native controls, but also include my own cast button, kind of what [video.js-chromecast](https://github.com/benjipott/video.js-chromecast) does, but the native button still shows up.

Is there anyway to reposition the Cast icon over the html5 video? or completely hide it ?

Comment: And here's the example page used http://jsfiddle.net/bentael/f1quhd2L/5/,  I also ended up complaining chez the Chrome team 
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=459083

Answer (score 22, accepted):

After searching the Chromium source code, I figured out how to do it:

```
video::-internal-media-controls-overlay-cast-button {
    display: none;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/f1quhd2L/8/

Comment: looks like `-internal-media-controls-overlay-cast-button` is being deprecated https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5714245488476160 for the `disableRemotePlayback` attribute.

Comment: any other solution?

Answer (score 35):

There is another options to disable casting button, this option actually disables the button instead of hiding it.

`<video disableRemotePlayback src="...">`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/disableRemotePlayback
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/11/presentation-api

Comment: Using react: disableremoteplayback="true"

Comment: disableRemotePlayback has been deprecated, any other solution?