# How to remove Cast button from Android browser's HTML5 video controls?

Tags: android, google-chrome, html5-video, chromecast, android-browser

I am building a videoplayer which has custom controls (play, pause, mute, seek etc) on desktop browsers. But on mobile devices, mobile OS (Android, iOS) show their native controls. When there is a cast device available on wifi network, Android Chrome browser also shows a Chromecast button in native controls. Upon tapping on it, I get `Unable to cast video due to site restrictions` toast error message. I could not find any useful resource about what could be the "site restriction" as we are not doing anything to restrict casting from mobile browsers.

Any pointers about what could be causing this particular error? and is there a way to force not showing this cast button in native controls till we fix this error?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28153166/android-chrome-chromecast-icon-over-html5-video-position) question may be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
video::-internal-media-controls-overlay-cast-button {
    display: none;
}



    video::-internal-media-controls-overlay-cast-button {
        display: none;
    }
<video src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" autoPlay muted loop playsInline></video>
```