# How to stop chromecast icon appearing in html5 video

Tags: html, video, icons, chromecast

The chromecast icon has recently started appearing in html5 players in both Chrome and Edge. Any idea why and how to remove? Although visible it's not showing up as an element in the dev console.

This jsfddle is showing me the cast icon in the html5 player.

https://jsfiddle.net/charkes/tpq493gx/2/

```
<video id='video' preload='auto' style="width: 300px;">
```

```
    $("#video").on("canplay", function() {
     $("#video")[0].play(); 
    });
```

[image: ghost cast icon]

Comment: I also noticed this appearing all of a sudden... weirdly it was only appearing for me in videos in the web app which I manage, but wasn't appearing in an HTML5 video test page I set up. Looking at your example I think the reason might be down to the `controls` attribute which I note isn't present in your jsfiddle. If I remove that attribute from my test, the cast button disappears.
It's kind of annoying as my webapp uses custom video player controls, which I guess is what's causing it to appear there.

Comment: OK I think I figured it out, if you add a `disableRemotePlayback` attribute to your `<video>` as per this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45142566/1646700 that should make it go away
Still can't figure out why this only started appearing within the past couple of days... I guess either something changed in a Chrome update - or I somehow managed to accidentally enable it via a keyboard shortcut...?

Comment: Thanks moloko. Same. Started happening after the last Chrome update a few days ago. But then I also noticed it in Edge so thought it may be a wi-fi issue. 

Adding disableRemotePlayback to the video tag fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a `disableRemotePlayback` attribute to your `<video>` tag as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45142566/1646700) that will prevent the cast button from appearing.

(Adding as a proper answer rather than just a comment)